# How can I fire delayed tracking event

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to fire a delayed tracking event form Active Campaign (email automation tool). They provide an event tracking example using php (see below). My first question is how should I go about firing this code? Php, javascript? When I use the 'sleep' function in php it delays the load of my page so I'm thinking I need to use javascript. Basically I need to know how to POST fields using javascript (or the best one) (also, I'm using this on Wordpress). Here is the php example AC provided:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://trackcmp.net/event");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "actid" => "aaaaaaa",
    "key" => "bbbbbbb",
    "event" => "EVENT_NAME",
    "eventdata" => "EVENT_DATA",
    "visit" => json_encode(array(
        // If you have an email address, assign it here.
            "email" => "",
            )),
        ));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result !== false) {
    $result = json_decode($result);
    if ($result->success) {
        echo 'Success! ';
    } else {
        echo 'Error! ';
    }

    echo $result->message;
} else {
    echo 'cURL failed to run: ', curl_error($curl);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

HC

Comment: As you mentioned, `sleep()` won't work, so you can either use ajax to send a separate request after the page has loaded, use pcntl to fork another process in the background, or save some sort of trigger to a database and use a cron job (or similar) to execute the tool at a set interval.